# How do I keep my extra life?

Tags: ios, prince-of-persia

I'm playing *Prince Of Persia Retro* for iOS. On an early level, I picked up a secret life potion. Now I am continuing my game using the Level select screen, but I start with 3 lives instead of having the 4th that I previously earned. Is there any way to keep my extra life across play sessions?